# Hide all text except for the first letter with CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is it possible to hide all letters after the first letter with CSS?

```
dt:not(::first-letter) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can, but your CSS is wrong. The version below works (at least in Chrome). It makes the `dt` invisible, and defines an overrule for the first letter to make it visible again.

I tried the same with `display` too, but that doesn't work, as expected. `visibility: hidden` hides the content, but keeps the element in place, while `display: none` removes it from the flow, and makes it impossible for sub-elements (the first letter in this case) to become visible again.

I added a hover too, so you can hover the letter to see the rest of the dt.

```css
dt {
  visibility: hidden;
}
dt::first-letter {
  visibility: visible;
}

/* Hover the first letter to see the rest */
dt:hover {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
Hover to see the rest:
<dt>Lorum ipsum is a weird text</dt>
<dt>Foo bar</dt>
```

A side effect will be that the area that is covered by the text is still claimed. Maybe that is not an issue, but if it is you will need some other solution. One possibility is to make the font-size of the `dt` `0` too. That way, the text is so small that is claims no space. Won't help if it also contains images, of course.

Since it doesn't seem to work, here is the alternative using font-size. Less than ideal, but hopefully it will still solve your problem.

```css
dt {
  font-size: 0;
}
dt::first-letter {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

/* Hover the first letter to see the rest */
dt:hover {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

```html
Hover to see the rest:
<dt>Lorum ipsum is a weird text</dt>
<dt>Foo bar</dt>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Firefox. Even hovering doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: Indeed. On FF the whole text is invisible, even the first letter. That shouldn't happen, since it should be allowed to make an element invisible while making parts of its content visible. Feels to me like a bug. However, as an alternative, you might consider not hiding the text, but making it transparent or settings the font-side to 0.

Comment: @Paulie_D `dt` should be block, but even if I add `display: block` to it, it doesn't help.

Comment: Interesting, the second snippet worked on Firefox (though there's a ~1px movement of the baselineon hover) until I went to fix your `rem` typo, at which point the behaviour was the same as the first.

Comment: @OrangeDog `rem` is not a typo. It's root-em. You have to specify a font size for the first letter, since it can't use the `0` of the `dt`. I used `rem`, which is the base em-size for the document, but you could also use some px value. If you use `em`, it's relative to the font-size of the `dt` element. Since that font-size is `0`, `1em` is also 0, and therefore the letter doesn't show up. That's why this solution is not ideal: you have to set some fixed font size here. There is no way to my knowledge to just use the 'original' size.

Comment: Ah, I see. In some cases `vw` or `bw` might be an option then.

Answer (score 11):

I think you can try this:

```css
.twitter{
      display: block;
      color: transparent;
    }

    .twitter:first-letter{
      color: #000;
    }
```

```html
 <div id="socialMedia">
    <a class="twitter">Twitter</a>
</div>
<div id="socialMedia">
    <a class="twitter">Google</a>
</div>
```

See also this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pLj3a5wv/1/)

Comment: Well, I partially take it back: Looks good and working in the JSFiddle, but not in the Stack Snippet. Will file a bug report later today.

Comment: please Check the fiddle link

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `:not` with pseudo element selector (see [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)).

What you can do is thinking in another way: transparent-ize the whole thing, then color with `::first-letter`. Because the latter has higher specificity, it will override the transparent setting, thus achieve the result you want.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative based on Waruna's answer, using `color` instead of layout-based attributes. Main advantage is that it works on every browser I tested (Firefox, Chrome and M$ Edge, but should probably work on all browsers), and it does not cause any visual glitches (like the "baseline jumping a pixel" from the second solution of the accepted answer), since it uses a completely visual attribute.

The issue with your original CSS is that you cannot use pseudo-elements (`::blah`) inside `:not`. You have to expand it into the inverse logic so you do not need the `:not`

```css
dt {
  color: transparent;
}
dt::first-letter {
  color: black;
}

/* For testing */
dt:hover {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<dt>Hello World!</dt>
```

Comment: Do we really need another answer for every possible way to make text invisible in css? At most this should be a comment on the accepted answer. "A third option is to use `color: transparent` to hide and `color: black` to show"

Comment: @alexanderbird This works on every browser without any visual glitchiness, unlike the accepted solution(s).

Comment: Ah! Would you add that to your answer? When I read it I was asking myself "what does this do that the others don't?"

Comment: @alexanderbird Sure, added a couple phrases on that.

Comment: Then again, a possible disadvantage here is that you can still select the text, although I admit that is probably less an issue than the jumpiness of my answer.

Comment: @GolezTrol a bit late, but [`user-select: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) can be used if you want that behaviour

Comment: @Kroltan Thanks for the addition! And lol, _a bit_ late he says ;)

Answer (score 0):

a bit late to the party but i found this solutuùion that may help someone

```
width: 1ch;
overflow: hidden;
```

It may not work for every font but it should. It is perfect for monospace as `ch` is the size of the O letter in a font, so if your first two letters are shorter than O it will work fine, otherwise you may have to tweak it a bit.

Change the ch and you can have the first 2, 3, 4 .... letters :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this....

```css
.newline1::first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #8A2BE2;
}
.newline2::first-letter {
  /*color: transparent;*/
font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="newline1">
Test Stackoverflow.com
</div>
<div class="newline2">
Test Stackoverflow.com
</div>
```

```css
.newline1::first-letter {
    font-size: 200%;
    color: #8A2BE2;
}
.newline2::first-letter {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="newline1">
Test Stackoverflow.com
</div>
<div class="newline2">
Test Stackoverflow.com
</div>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The problem is not *hiding* the first letter, but hiding *the rest* of the letters...

Comment: This is answering a completely different question to the one being asked. I should probably downvote this answer.