# Show first character of the word and show full word on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to show first character of a word using `::first-letter` css property,

I have set up following code pen example but is not working for me not sure if i made any mistake.

```
<div class="slide">
<a target="_blank" href="#" class="post-badge btn_six">TECHNOLOGY</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.post-badge {visibility: hiddenx;  font-size:50px; display: inline-block;}
.post-badge::first-letter {visibility:visible; display:block;}
a{color:red;}
.slide{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#f5f5f5;
}
.btn_six:hover{visibility: visible; color:green;display:inline-block; }
```

I have delibrate made `.post-badge {visibility: hiddenx;` with x at end otherwise it is not showing anyting.

How can i fix this so that it only show **T** and when i hover over it then it show full the word **TECHNOLOGY**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rpPKvJ

Comment: @Paulie_D, It is deliberate TYPO i have mentioned this in my question, Please read teh question, even if you remove `x` from `hidden` it is still not working. i wrote `hiddenx` so that you can see the whole word

Comment: It clearly works (in Chrome) as I showed in the demo....if this is **browser specific** you need to edit the question to indicate that.

Comment: Hmmm...FF Quantum and Edge seem to have this issue. Chrome does not.

Comment: Aha....dupe  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36836570/hide-all-text-except-for-the-first-letter-with-css/36836742#36836742

Comment: @Learning A better title for this question might be something like: 'Firefox: visibility property not working within ::first-letter pseudo-element'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing `visibility` you could change `font-size` on hover.

```css
.post-badge {
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: font-size 0.3s ease-in;
  line-height: 1;
}
.post-badge::first-letter {
  font-size: 50px;
}
.slide {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
.btn_six:hover {
  visibility: visible;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
  <a target="_blank" href="#" class="post-badge btn_six">TECHNOLOGY</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That is a cool trick, but my question is still why doesn't it work with visibility

Answer (score 3):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter), and [this w3C wiki](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-elements/:first-letter#Point.2C_Note) the first-letter pseudo element only supports a subset of CSS properties. (from the wiki:)

> The following properties that apply to ::first-letter pseudo-elements:
>   font properties
>
> ‘text-decoration’
>
> ‘text-transform’
>
> ‘letter-spacing’
>
> ‘word-spacing’
>
> ‘line-height’
>
> ‘float’
>
> ‘vertical-align’ (only if ‘float’ is ‘none’)
>
> margin properties
>
> padding properties
>
> border properties
>
> color property
>
> background properties

The visibility property doesn't appear in that list.

According to this, Firefox seems to be according to spec and not Chrome.

As a workaround, consider using Nenad's solution.

Comment: Which browser are you using? I don't see that happening.

Comment: Latest version of FF